# Merging lines after condition

Tags: python

I have a dataset from a txt file, where each line contains 4 data points, separated by a space. Due to some error when the data was collected, some lines are broken up into two lines and a couple of spaces appear instead of actual data. Thus the input is supposed to look like this:

```
data data data data
data data data data
data data data data
```

but does in fact look like this (the second line has three spaces in the end and the third starts with three spaces):

```
data data data data
data data   
   data
data data data data
```

I want to add "n/a" for the missing data and merge the second and third line, in the second example, into one line. Finally I want to save this as a new file.

This is my attempt:

```
f1 = open("pilTest.txt","r") 
f2 = open("pilFix.txt", "w") 
stop = 0
for line in f1: 
    # Loop over each word in line 
    words = line.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if len(words[i])!=0:
            f2.write(words[i])
            f2.write(" ")
        elif stop==0:            
            f2.write("n/a")
            f2.write(" ")
            stop = 1
```

Suggestions?

What I get is

```
data data data data
data data n/a
data
data data data data
```

The desired output is

```
data data data data
data data n/a data
data data data data
```

Comment: It it not working? If so how is it not working? What does it (not) do? What did you expect it to do and what did it do?

Comment: It is not working. It outputs an "n/a" after the second line, but I can't get it to add the third line to the second line. I'll add a desired output.

Comment: Do you know it's always the third column where the "n/a" goes? Or do you get that information from the line break after the second column and the extra spaces in front of the next row?

Comment: I don't know where the "n/a" goes unfortunately. I think it always goes in the same place. In the actual data set I have 19 columns and the error occurs mostly (perhaps only?) in the 17th column.

Comment: You're splitting on a single space: that leaves the newline attached to the last "word", which you are also printing. So `rstrip` the line you read from the file, and add the newline yourself once you're done with a line (or combining two lines). Because that extra newline you're seeing, comes directly from your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's something significant about the spaces, you might want to analyse those. Alternatively, working on the assumption that the error arises when data goes missing, and that it goes missing in the middle of the broken line, retroactively filling in the missing data might work:

```
f1 = open("pilTest.txt","r") 
f2 = open("pilFix.txt", "w")

_last_words = []
_expected_length = 4
for line in f1: 
    words = line.split()
    if len(words) != _expected_length:
        if _last_words:
            blanks = _expected_length - (len(_last_words) + len(words))
            f2.write(' '.join(_last_words + ['n/a']*blanks + words) + '\n')
            _last_words = []
        else:
            _last_words = words
    else:
        f2.write(line)

f2.close()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! The actual data points may be anything from a 0 or 1 to strings (w/o spaces), so I changed _expected_length to 1 and

    if len(words) != _expected_length:
to
    if len(words) <= _expected_length:

Comment: Ok, it almost solved the problem. The "third line" doesn't show up, and I get no "n/a". I'll check the code again. I'm sorry if I underspecified the problem.

Comment: I should clarify the _expected_length refers to how many elements you expect on a line, not how long the elements are - that 'data' is four characters long was a coincidence.

Comment: Aha! Ok, I'll give that a go.